# Average measure for all GPS points within certain range

Tags: python, pandas, gps, pandas-groupby, distance

I have a pandas dataframe with latitude, longitude, and a measure for 100K+ GPS points.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat': [41.260637, 45.720185, 45.720189, 45.720214, 45.720227, 46.085716, 46.085718, 46.085728, 46.085730, 46.085732], 
          'lng': [2.825920, 3.068014, 3.068113, 3.067929, 3.068199, 3.341655, 3.341534, 3.341476, 3.341546, 3.341476], 
      'measure': [6.30000, -0.375000, -0.375000, -0.375000, -0.375000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.555556, 0.714286, 0.645833]})
```

What I want to do is calculate, for each of these points, the average of the measure column for all points within a range of 10 meters.

I know how to calculate the distance between two points using `geopy`

```
from geopy.distance import distance
distance([gps_points.lat[3], gps_points.lng[3]], [gps_points.lat[4], gps_points.lng[4]]).m
```

> 21.06426497936181

But how would I go iterating on rows, selecting points in the 10m range and averaging the measure?

I'm guessing some sort of groupby, but can't figure out how.

Comment: I found a similar question on GIS Stack Exchange, which did not get its answer on the matter: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251298/python-collect-all-points-that-meet-a-criteria-for-every-point-in-the-shapefile

Comment: the way the question is defined its pure brute force, may be if you change it to calculate avg for all the points in a region, then you can use sklearn methods or something of that sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, the point itself is always included itself. Making it part of the average itself. You would need to modify that part if you want to exclude the  point itself.

We can use BallTree

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import numpy as np
```

And with your sample data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat': [41.260637, 45.720185, 45.720189, 45.720214, 45.720227, 46.085716, 46.085718, 46.085728, 46.085730, 46.085732], 
          'lng': [2.825920, 3.068014, 3.068113, 3.067929, 3.068199, 3.341655, 3.341534, 3.341476, 3.341546, 3.341476], 
      'measure': [6.30000, -0.375000, -0.375000, -0.375000, -0.375000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.555556, 0.714286, 0.645833]})
```

We can create a Tree with

```
gps_pairs = df[["lat", "lng"]].values
radians =  np.radians(gps_pairs)

tree = BallTree(radians, leaf_size=15, metric='haversine')
```

Now we need to scale to get radius of 10m (approx):

```
distance_in_meters = 10
earth_radius = 6371000
    
radius = distance_in_meters / earth_radius
```

Query that `radius` with

```
is_within, distances = tree.query_radius(radians, r=radius, count_only=False, return_distance=True)
```

`is_within` will contain the indices of points that fall within 10 meter.

Now you can calculate the average measure with:

```
measures = df[['measure']].values

average_measure_for_withins = np.array([ np.mean( measures[withins] ) for withins in is_within ])
```

And for instance add this to the DF

```
df['average_for_withins'] = average_measure_for_withins
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot!
That was exactly what I was looking for, and I did want to include the point itself in the average.
I had never heard of BallTree so far, will have to look deeper into it.